# Delays on ffmpeg with rtsp streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, ip-camera

I have a command

```
ffmpeg -threads 0 -i rtsp://user:pass@10.10.10.1 -threads 0 -i rtsp://user:pass@10.10.10.2 -map 0:1 -map 1:1  -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 -muxdelay 0 -ar 22050 -vn -f flv rtmp://10.10.10.3:1935/live/stream1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -muxdelay 0 -ar 22050 -f flv rtmp://10.10.10.3:1935/live/stream4 -map 1:0 -map 1:1 -muxdelay 0 -ar 22050 -f flv rtmp://10.10.10.3:1935/live/stream5
```

It does 3 things: 
1) takes audio from both ip cameras (10.10.10.1 and 10.10.10.2) - and muxes them in one mp3 stream (stream1).
2) takes audio and video from cam 10.10.10.1 and streams it to rtmp://10.10.10.3:1935/live/stream4
3) takes audio and video from cam 10.10.10.2 and streams it to rtmp://10.10.10.3:1935/live/stream5

Problem: Delays:
1) Delay from reality: I smile in Cam1 and I see my smile on the Stream4 in 4-5 seconds.
2) different delays on different cameras. Both cameras look at me, I say "Hello". First camera shows my "Hello", then in 4-5 seconds the second camera shows "Hello", and in 2-3 second I hear "Hello" on the Stream1.

The most important and disturbing problem is the second one. Please help solving it. I want them to be simultaneous - both cameras and audioStream.

Thank you in advance.

```
P.S. Full output

[root@minjust ~]# ffmpeg -threads 0 -i rtsp://user:pass@172.22.5.201 -threads 0 -i rtsp://user:pass@172.22.5.202 -map 0:1 -map 1:1  -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 -muxdelay 0 -ar 22050 -vn -f flv rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -muxdelay 0 -ar 22050 -f flv rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream4 -map 1:0 -map 1:1 -muxdelay 0 -ar 22050 -f flv rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream5
ffmpeg version N-76031-g9099079 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration:
  libavutil      55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
  libavcodec     57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavformat    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:pass@172.22.5.201':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.073000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 10 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 20 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 16000 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
Input #1, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:pass@172.22.5.202':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.064000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 704x576, 12 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 24 tbc
    Stream #1:1: Audio: adpcm_g726, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 16 kb/s
    Stream #1:2: Data: none
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    encoder         : Lavf57.4.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: adpcm_swf ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 88 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.6.100 adpcm_swf
Output #1, flv, to 'rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream4':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    encoder         : Lavf57.4.100
    Stream #1:0: Video: flv1 (flv) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 10 fps, 1k tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.6.100 flv
    Stream #1:1: Audio: adpcm_swf ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 88 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.6.100 adpcm_swf
Output #2, flv, to 'rtmp://172.22.45.38:1935/live/stream5':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    encoder         : Lavf57.4.100
    Stream #2:0: Video: flv1 (flv) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 704x576, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 12 fps, 1k tbn, 12 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.6.100 flv
    Stream #2:1: Audio: adpcm_swf ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 88 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.6.100 adpcm_swf
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (mp2) -> amix:input0 (graph 0)
  Stream #1:1 (g726) -> amix:input1 (graph 0)
  amix (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (adpcm_swf)
  Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (h264 (native) -> flv1 (flv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #1:1 (mp2 (native) -> adpcm_swf (native))
  Stream #1:0 -> #2:0 (h264 (native) -> flv1 (flv))
  Stream #1:1 -> #2:1 (adpcm_g726 (g726) -> adpcm_swf (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtsp @ 0x35af820] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[rtsp @ 0x34e1b60] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
Past duration 0.930214 too large
Past duration 0.647987 too large
Past duration 0.730217 too large
...
```

Comment: full console output please? anyway my first guess is it's being transcoded by a video codec that requires a lot of "buffering" (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide describes libx264 zerolatency which is popular)

Comment: yeah my guess is the flv codec introduces some latency, FWIW

Comment: thanx. I tried using x264 - the situation is better. But I still have 1 second difference between cameras and 2-3 seconds delay for mixed audio. What format do you recomend? And in general: is it possible at all? I need to take simultaneously audio-video streams from 2-3 ip-cameras and plus to this one mixed audio stream (also simultaneous) from all cameras. Can you recommend a command for this or give some advise?

Comment: unfortunately all I know about latency is in that streaming guide link, sorry!